# Need to fix small loop bug

Tags: linux, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

hi i have a problem with my loop, it says syntax error near unexpected token 'fi' 
i don't know where is the little problem
but i need my if loop and my for loop to work:

```
if [ var1 == true ] then 
 for ip in $(seq 90 254); do ping -c 1 188.118.28.$ip;
done
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

you have a missing ";" before "then"

```
if [ var1 == true ]; then 
    for ip in $(seq 90 254); do ping -c 1 188.118.28.$ip; 
    done
fi
```

Comment: It's When you accept answers that actually answer your questions  :) (right under the vote up/down)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
if $var1; then
  for ip in $(seq 90 254); do ping -c 1 188.118.28.$ip;
  done;
fi
```

and for completeness: I set var1 like this:

```
var1=true
```